# Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection and add it in another document as reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Suppose you have the following documents in my collection:

```
{  

"_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192"),
"name": "Asset1"
   "shapes":[  
      {  
     "_id": "5cf10fea4cb6352abcfe094b",
         "shape":"square",
         "color":"blue"
      },
      {  
     "_id": "5cf10fea4cb6352abcfe094c",
         "shape":"circle",
         "color":"red"
      }
   ]
},

{  
   "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4193"),
   "name": "Asset2"
   "shapes":[  
      {  
     "_id": "5c7524f76792cf28f80793e3"
         "shape":"square",
         "color":"black"
      },
      {  
     "_id": "5c7524f76792cf28f80793e4"
         "shape":"circle",
         "color":"green"
      }
   ]
}
}
```

I do not have problem in finding a particular color like this also it is working

```
  Test.find(
    {"shapes.color": "red"}, 

    //Match the exact color
    {
      products: {
        $elemMatch: { color: "red" }
      }
    }
  )
```

The main problem is I want to add this Asset1 and take only color red not the whole array by referencing `ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192")` it in test2 collection. How do I do this using Mongoose?

This is the Test2 Schema where I did referencing

```
const Test2Schema = new Schema({
anothername: String,
test1Shape: {
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: "Test"
  },
});
```

Comment: what is products here in find query?

Comment: sorry its just my naming convention for the assets @ManjeetThakur

Comment: I apologize for writing such phrase in my question, certainly it was not a good idea and next time I will be more careful and refrain from using such phrase. Thank You for your information @halfer

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query, it uses [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) , [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

$unwind - To unwind the Shapes array

$match  - To filter the matching color `red` records

$lookup - To lookup the matching documents in Test2 Collection

$out    - To override the Test2 collection with the merged document

```
db.Test1.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$shapes"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "shapes.color": "red"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Test2",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "mergeResult"
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "Test2"
  }
]);
```